# How do I use a CSV file received from a URL query in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv

How do I use comma-separated-value (CSV) file received from a URL query in Objective-C? When I query the URL I get CSV data such as

```
"OMRUAH=X",20.741,"3/16/2010","1:52pm",20.7226,20.7594
```

How do I parse and use this for my application?

My problem is creating/initializing that `NSString` object in the first place. An example is this link http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv which returns CSV. I don't know how to parse this into an object since I cannot use an `NSXMLParser` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code using `-componentsSeparatedByString:` which will end up with an NSArray of each component separated by:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv"];
NSString *reply = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *csvItems = [reply componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Claus

Comment: Works prefect! merci :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tools:

1. http://michael.stapelberg.de/cCSVParse
2. http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ReadWriteCSVAndTSV

Here's an example of using `NSScanner`: http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data